# RuntimeException from Cloud Dataflow related to serializing Coder

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm having an odd issue running my Dataflow pipeline. I have written my own Coder, but switching that out with AvroCoder, SerializableCoder and other examples have produced the same issue.

Here is the exception I am getting, after trying to launch the pipeline using Dataflow Service in streaming mode:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deserialize Coder: ModelCoder. Check that a suitable constructor is defined.  See Coder for details.
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.ensureSerializable(SerializableUtils.java:113)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.ensureCoderSerializable(DirectPipelineRunner.java:901)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.ensurePCollectionEncodable(DirectPipelineRunner.java:861)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.setPCollectionValuesWithMetadata(DirectPipelineRunner.java:789)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.setPCollection(DirectPipelineRunner.java:776)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO.evaluateReadHelper(TextIO.java:786)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO.access$000(TextIO.java:118)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO$Read$Bound$1.evaluate(TextIO.java:327)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO$Read$Bound$1.evaluate(TextIO.java:323)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.visitTransform(DirectPipelineRunner.java:706)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:219)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:215)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:102)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:252)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:662)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:374)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:87)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:174)
  at io.momentum.demo.models.pipeline.PlatformPipeline.main(PlatformPipeline.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Sub-class com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils$Jackson2Module$Resolver MUST implement `typeFromId(DatabindContext,String)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeIdResolverBase.typeFromId(TypeIdResolverBase.java:77)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:156)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:106)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:91)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:142)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:42)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3760)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2042)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:2529)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.Serializer.deserialize(Serializer.java:98)
  at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.ensureSerializable(SerializableUtils.java:110)
  ... 18 more
```

My implementation `Coder` just wraps `AvroCoder` and hooks into some of our own code:

```
public final class ModelCoder<M extends AppModel> extends AtomicCoder<M> {
  public static <T extends AppModel> ModelCoder<T> of(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new ModelCoder<>(clazz);
  }

  @JsonCreator
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static ModelCoder<?> of(@JsonProperty("kind") String classType) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classType);
    return of((Class<? extends AppModel>) clazz);
  }

  private String kind;

  public ModelCoder(Class<M> type) {
    this.kind = type.getSimpleName();
  }

  @Override
  public void encode(M value, OutputStream outStream, Context context) throws IOException, CoderException {
    CoderInternals.encode(value, outStream, context, new TypeReference<TypedSerializedModel<M>>() { });
  }

  @Override
  public M decode(InputStream inStream, Context context) throws IOException, CoderException {
    return CoderInternals.decode(inStream, context, new TypeReference<TypedSerializedModel<M>>() { });
  }

  @Override
  public CloudObject asCloudObject() {
    CloudObject co = super.asCloudObject();
    co.set("kind", kind);
    return co;
  }
}
```

The coder works as expected when it is invoked to `encode(..)` or `decode(..)` an `AppModel`, but this exception occurs anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You need a static method tagged with @JsonCreator so that the service can instantiate your coder on the workers.  You also shouldn't overwrite asCloudObject(); that determines how your Coder will be serialized and sent to the workers, and your code will just send a serialized AvroCoder.

For example, take a look at NullableCoder.java (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/NullableCoder.java) for an example of a Coder that wraps another one.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @danielm. I have edited my code to more accurately reflect what I'm trying to do.

`AppModel` is an abstract polymorphic base, so I'm adding the `kind` property to be able to resolve the type during deserialization. My coder now uses pretty simple objects, and has a `@JsonCreator` (see above), but still produces the exception shown.

Comment: Jackson 2.5.0+ requires TypeIdResolvers to implement typeFromId(DatabindContext,String) which the Dataflow SDK does not within [CoderUtils.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/CoderUtils.java#L250). Please verify that you are using Jackson 2.4.5.